# Spark 1.5.1 spark-shell throws RuntimeException

Tags: apache-spark

I am simply trying to launch the spark shell on my local Windows 8 and here's the error message that i get :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are:
 rw-rw-rw-
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1028)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
    at <init>(<console>:20)
    at .<init>(<console>:24)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
    ... 56 more
```

Somehow the REPL is here, but i can't use the sqlContext..

Did anyone faced this problem before? Any answer will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: It says: `/tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable`. Do you even have such a directory ? Also this seem like a UNIX style path.

Comment: Indeed I am not aware of this directory, this might be created by hadoop when the spark-shell is launched i guess

Comment: I don't think spark-shell will invoke any hadoop related function, unless you ask Spark to do so. You might want to describe the steps you took, and also mention which version of spark you used.

Comment: I unziped everything then ran the spark-shell, altough the 1.3.0 is working fine.

Comment: Report it to Apache Spark project.

Comment: This looks to be a new problem with 1.5.1 on windows: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10528

Comment: Actually, it shows up in 1.5.0, and I found it's still there with 1.5.1

Answer (score 2):

RESOLVED : Downloaded the correct Winutils version and issue was resolved. Ideally, it should be locally compiled but if downloading compiled version make sure that it is 32/64 bit as applicable.
I tried on Windows 7 64 bit, Spark 1.6 and downloaded winutils.exe from https://www.barik.net/archive/2015/01/19/172716/ and it worked..!!
Complete Steps are at : http://letstalkspark.blogspot.com/2016/02/getting-started-with-spark-on-window-64.html

Answer (score 2):

First you need to download the correct compatible winutils.exe for your spark and operating system.  Place it somewhere in folder followed by **bin** directory.
Lets say `D:\winutils\bin\winutils.exe`

Now if /tmp/hive is present in your D: drive, run following command:

```
D:\winutils\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 D:\tmp\hive
```

For more details, refer these posts:

[Frequent Issues occurred during Spark Development](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2016/04/frequent-issues-occurred-during-spark.html)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10528

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful in this case :
**https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10528**

Comment: Can you expand on why it might be helpful?